# Configuring Tomcat instances on windows server

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I was configuring tomcat instances(Tomcat7 and Tomcat71) on same server, Tomcat7 is already present and when I am installing Windows service for Tomcat71, I gave below command:

cd C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin

Tomcat7.exe //IS//Tomcat7

My problem is I gave service name which is already existing instead of new service name for eg. Tomcat71. So, the port number for service Tomcat7 might changed and I am not able to listen port "80" in "Apache http server".Can anyone help me in solving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a conf directory in "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0" ?

Comment: Yes I have that directory.

Comment: Then you should change the port entries in server.xml file inside "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf". There are three entries for 3 different types of ports shutdown, http and ajp. Three should be different for 2 servers.